# I’m exploring names for a fictional space agency. Which would be more correct?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

I’d like it to have the acronym "ET"

Would it be better for it to be:

> excelsior terra

or

> excelsior tellus

I’m sure that there are better ways to express this though I have always liked the word *excelsior* and I like the feminine aspect of *tellus*.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify what the words are supposed to mean. Both phrases are perfectly legal Latin but make little sense as the name of a government agency. *Excelsior terra* literally means “higher ground.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the word *terra* is the usual way of speaking of the Earth, some form of *tellūs* is also a possibility. The latter is used in this sense most commonly in poetry. According to the lexicon of [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=tellus&la=la#lexicon), it is defined as:

> tellus — the earth, opp. to the other planets or to the sea, the globe
>   (a word belonging almost entirely to poetry).

My first impression was that you were trying to express "of the Earth", in which case the **genitive** form would be used. However, the word *excelsior* is a comparative adjective which suggests the comparison "Higher than the Earth". In that case the **ablative** should be used. In order to make it clear that *excelsior* doesn't describe *terra* (in which case it would mean *higher ground*), it might be better to use the plural form of *excelsior*:

> Excelsiōrēs Terrā

Using the **ablative** form of *tellūs*:

> Excelsiōrēs Tellūre

If, on the other hand, you *did* want to use the **genitive** ("...*of the Earth*"), it would be:

> Excelsiōrēs Terrae

Using the **genitive** form of *tellūs*:

> Excelsiōrēs Tellūris

Comment: What would it mean though? I'd translate it as something like "loftier of Earth" which doesn't make very much sense to me.

Comment: @JasperMay. I think it would sound better with articles, such as "the nobler of the Earth" —  kind of like "the upper crust".

Comment: I guess pars or gens could be understood, if the OP insists on the word form 'excelsior'. But maybe 'excelsiores' would make it more immediately obvious that it's referring to a group of people. Or what about 'Excelsiùs Terrâ' (higher than the Earth), an adverbial phrase like 'per ardua ad astra'.

Comment: @JasperMay. *Excelsior* was chosen as the motto for the state of [New York](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excelsior), so I don't know why there would be a problem with keeping it in the singular. However, I think you might be right that the ablative would be a better choice.

Comment: Ok, you may be right about Excelsior. I do prefer the ablative.

Comment: @JasperMay. I changed my mind about the plural form because of Sebastian's comment about "higher ground".

Comment: Sure, excelsior terra, in macronless Latin, could mean either 'higher ground' or 'higher than the ground (Earth)'.